# Custom theme of a layout in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do this as shown in picture. I want my relative layout to look like this. How can i do that. Themes, styles etc. Just give me hint and ideas

Best Regards

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this :

create folder in res called:( drawable ) ,then create XML called ( row_shape.xml ) as shape inside it ,then write this on it :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp" android:color="your color" /> 
  <solid android:color="your color" /> 
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"
       android:bottom="2dp" /> 
  <corners android:radius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" 
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

then in layout Xml refer to shape as :
 android:background="@drawable/row_shape"

HOPE THIS HELP

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is vague, I'm not quite sure where you stand code wise. But here is a link that will bring you to the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) relating to themes and how to implement them.